# Issue with AnimationDrawable

Tags: android

I have one issue with AnimationDrawable. I want the background shown after stoping the frameAnimation to be the same as the background shown before starting the frameAnimation. Unfortunately it isn't, because when the frameAnimation stops, the background image is set to the last ImageView show by frameAnimation.

is there any way to fix it?

```
ImageView view;

gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            view=(ImageView)v;
            frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) v.getBackground();
            frameAnimation.start();
            myDataThread=new Thread(new DataThread());
            myDataThread.start();

        }
    });

public class DataThread implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
    //do smth
    view.stop();
    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.connectbutton);
    }
}
```

Comment: on animation end you can reset the background resource how about that ?

Comment: how could i reset it?

Comment: view.setBackgroundResource(someotherresource or null);

Comment: Unfortunately I get this exception: `android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable`

Comment: okay, I've posted it. I'm actually getting the exception the second time I tap on the image, but not the first.

Comment: First of all remove the thread you cant access the views from another thread directly so remove it you can simply set the animation drawable when ever you wanted and add an animation listener when animation is complete change the background resource

Comment: well, I've also tried using a handle inside the thread to access the views... I'll try the animation listener as you mentioned

Comment: animation listener is not available for AnimationDrawable :(

Answer (score 1):

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        view=(ImageView)v;
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_frame_animation_id);
        AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) view.getBackground();
        frameAnimation.start();

        view.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                if(frameAnimation.getCurrent() != frameAnimation.getFrame(frameAnimation.getNumberOfFrames() - 1))
                {
                    view.post(this);
                }else
                {
                    view.removeCallbacks(this);
                    view.setBackgroundResource(R.id.some_image_resource);
                }

            }
        });
    }
});
```

Change your `setOnItemClickListener` like this, by default the frame animation will be looping. Also you may want to reset the background when `getView` method is called for the `Adapter` that you have set for the `GridView`. For animation listener you can do some thing like get total number of frames and multiply it with the duration of a single frame. Or do this

view.post()

Comment: well, it actually solves the problem, however what I want is to be able to stop the animation when a certain event occurs, and not just display the set of images one after another and stops it when the last image is reached. This implementation seems to have unabled me to do this.